# "Declare" clause before "Begin" clause in CREATE PROCEDURE

Tags: sql-server

I wonder whether there is any difference between these two options of declaring variables in stored procedures? Any drawbacks?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.HelloWorld
AS
    DECLARE @message NVARCHAR(30)
BEGIN
    SET @message = 'Hello World!'
    SELECT @message
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.HelloWorld2
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @message NVARCHAR(30)
    SET @message = 'Hello World!'
    SELECT @message
END
GO
```

Comment: There is no difference. `BEGIN` *should* be after `AS`, however, that are not mandated. You could just as well write the statement without `BEGIN...END`. Personally I would do it after `BEGIN` as it just looks odd otherwise.

Comment: I tend to treat `BEGIN` and `END` as analogous to `{` and `}` in C#, and I wouldn't put variable declarations used in a method body, outside the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference.  A stored procedure body is simply zero-or-more TSQL statements, and is terminated by the end of the batch containing the CREATE PROCEDURE: it's the `GO` that ends the procedure not the `END`.  This is why CREATE PROCEDURE must be the only statement in the batch.

The `BEGIN..END` around the stored procedure body is purely conventional, but is a strongly-recommended best-practice.

If you want to implement a pattern with forward declaration of variables ahead of a `BEGIN..END` block you may.  But it's unnecessary to declare all your variables at the top, and in languages that don't require forward declaration, it's typically considered poor form.

Answer (score 1):

No real difference basically the first one is the same as writing this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.HelloWorld
AS
   BEGIN
     DECLARE @message NVARCHAR(30)  
     BEGIN
       SET @message = 'Hello World!'
       SELECT @message
     END
   END
GO
```

There is an implied code block after the AS.

cf https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15